# Parsing Web Data in Python (Using Strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, text

I have a Python list from some web scraping that looks like the list below.

```
['\n           Elementary School: HUTCHINSON \n           High School: RIVERSIDE \n           Middle School: ROLLING RIDGE \n  ... ]
```

My goal is to retrieve the high school name of each listing I pull. For this particular listing, the high school is RIVERSIDE. What is the best way to extract this information?

My goal is to have a variable `hs = "RIVERSIDE"` for this particular listing.

Side note: this data is from housing listings on realtor.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ls=['\n           Elementary School: HUTCHINSON \n           High School: RIVERSIDE \n           Middle School: ROLLING RIDGE \n ']


hs=[i.strip().split(':')[1].replace('\n','') for i in ls[0].split('\n') if 'High School' in i][0]
print('hs =',hs)
```

Output:

```
hs =  RIVERSIDE
```

Or you can use `re`:

```
import re 
highschoolregex = re.compile(r'(High School)[:] (\w.+)') 
hs = highschoolregex.search(ls[0]).group(2)
print('hs =',hs)
```

Output:

```
hs =  RIVERSIDE
```